# How can I search an XML file and output the results to data grid for editing?

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

This can be done by using SQL, however I would like to use an XML file to have that ease for the user. I can make it display the data in the data-grid-view normally, but I'm not sure how to search for it as you normally would in an SQL database.

All I need to do is allow the person to search for a name, information or the day visited to put the data in the data-grid-view.

Following is my XML code:

```
<root>
  <place>
    <Name>home</Name>
    <Location>x-292 z 277</Location>
    <Info>home</Info>
    <Dayvisited>10</Dayvisited>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>town</Name>
    <Location>x 990 z-2485</Location>
    <Info>gas station</Info>
    <Dayvisited>12</Dayvisited>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>crossing</Name>
    <Location>x 90 z-2998</Location>
    <Info>working stiff</Info>
    <Dayvisited>11</Dayvisited>
  </place>
</root>
```

this is how i made it load in to a grid so far

```
ds.ReadXml("Database.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false;
```

im new at using xml files so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try using LINQtoXML libraries where you can query similar to SQL Database . Just load the xml to XDocument class and run the LINQ Queries

Comment: What you did so far is perfect.  Root is the name of the DataSet.Place is the table name of the first Datatable.  The columns names are the tag name of the children of place.  So you can use ds.Tables["place"] instead of ds.Tables[0].

Comment: i was looking at LINQ but i couldn't find anyone who explained it in a way i could use it for this

Comment: To search for locations: `XDocument doc =  XDocument.Parse(yourXmlText); var f = doc.Descendants("Location").Where(x => x.Value.Contains(yourSearchText)).ToList();`

Comment: @TaW when i try that it tells me. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Really? With the above data? How did you write the code?

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("Database.xml"); var f = doc.Descendants("Location").Where(x => x.Value.Contains("x-292 z 277")).ToList();
        
            dataGridView2.DataSource = f.ToList();  
but i assume i did it wrong i never really looked in to this much sorry

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the issue of putting the result to the dgv.. It is a simple list of xml entries..

Comment: so how should i put it to the dgv? sorry for the newby questions

Comment: Well, Don't you already have the data in the DGV? Wouldn't it be simpler to hide all but the ones found??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplfy the task by keeping the data in only one `DataGridView` and hiding those rows that don't match the search string.

Since you already have loaded the `XML` into a `DataTable` and **bound** a `DataGridView` to it we don't really need to search in the `XML` data..

The way to go for data-bound `DGVs` is to set a `Filter` on the `DataSource`. For this we need to insert a `DataView` between the `DGV` and the `DataTable`.

Let's start by filling a `ComboBox` with the `DataTable`'s `Columns`:

```
combo_fields.Items.AddRange(ds.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                .Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray());
combo_fields.SelectedIndex = 1;  // start with the Location field
```

Next we add a `TextBox` where we enter the search text:

```
private void tb_filter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filter = ""; 
    if (tb_filter.Text != "")
        filter = combo_fields.Text + " LIKE '*" + tb_filter.Text + "*'";

    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
    dv.RowFilter = filter;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

That is really all we need. Of course you can easily change the condition from a 'like' to a full match..

---

You could also search in the `XML` data and hide rows from the `DGV`, but it won't get any simpler than the above code, just a little closer to your original question..

Here is how to search an `XDocument xDoc`:

```
var found = xDoc.Descendants(combo_fields.Text)
                .Where(x => x.Value.Contains( tb_filter.Text))
                .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Now you can use the list of `strings` to decide which rows we will hide:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;  // necessary, so we don't try to hide the current row

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[combo_fields.Text].Value != null)
        row.Visible = found.Contains(row.Cells["Location"].Value.ToString());
}
```

After  we are done we can clear the filter `TextBox` to bring up all rows and and we can save the data..:

```
tb_filter.Text = "";

ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(someFileName);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. iv not seen anyone explain it this much. iv just seen patches of info.